# Find the value of the direct stress $\sigma_y$ when the value of the shear stress is given.

Tags: trigonometry, fluid-dynamics

[image]

> The relationship between shear stress $\sigma_y$ and direct stress $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y $ was found to be of the form:
>
> $$\tag{1} \sigma = \frac{\sigma_x - \sigma_y}{2}~ \sin e (2\theta) $$
>
> Find the value of the direct stress $\sigma_y$ when the value of the shear stress $\sigma$ is $25~\text{MNm}^{-2}$, the value of $\sigma_x$ is $80~\text{MNm}^{-2}$ and the value of the angle of the plane $\theta$ to the horizontal is $25^{\circ}$

Looking for help with this.

Would I use a hyperbolic function for this?

$$ \sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} $$

Comment: In Equation 1, what is $e$ ? In the argument of the sine function? And why do you think hyperbolic functions would be relevant here?

Comment: What is M,N,m ? If you replace sigma-x , sigma and theta in your equation, it seems that you have only one unknown variable left which is sigma-y right?

Comment: @Jeanba $\text{MNm}^{-2}$ is the units, meganewtons per metre squared.

Comment: @Jeanba yes that is correct, only unknown variable is sigma - y. I am just a bit stuck whilst trying to learn this.

Comment: I think all you have to do here is rearrange

Comment: $$\sigma y = \frac{ \sigma x - \sigma }{2}  Sine e (2 \theta)$$ To this?

Comment: If you're given the values of the direct stress $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$, then you don't need hyperbolic functions. 

I'm not sure what $e$ is referring to...either the traditional $e$=2.718281828..., Young's Modulus (E), or strain ($\varepsilon$).

Comment: i am not sure what $$e$$ is either. i was thinking $$e=2.718281828$$ also. Still trying to work out how to complete this, struggling to find information on how to complete it.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the usual "sine" function -often abbreviated by "sin"- that we are simply dealing with here? Never saw in physics a sine of exponential personally

Comment: @Jeanba i have attached the original question so you can see. I'm trying to learn this so not sure myself. Maybe you will able to see now.

Comment: Still Stuck on this. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Is the answer I provided helping you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as fGDu94 said, it's just a matter of rearranging the equation.

> $$\tag{1} \sigma = \frac{\sigma_x - \sigma_y}{2} \sin e (2\theta) $$

leads to

$$ \sigma_y =\sigma_x-\frac{(2\sigma)}{\sin e (2\theta)}  $$

By replacing with the given values we obtain:

$$ \sigma_y = 80 - \frac{(2*25)}{\sin e (2*25deg)}\\= 80 - \frac{(2*25)}{\sin e (2*\frac{25*Pi}{180}rad)} \\= 80-71.8663237517.. \\=8.13367624827.. \approx 8
  $$

NB: if the exponential function in the sine function happens to be a typo, the result would then become:

$$ \sigma_y =\sigma_x-\frac{(2\sigma)}{\sin (2\theta)} \\= 80- 65.2703644666.. = 14.7296355334..\approx 15$$